How to check compatibility between npm packages
How to check compatibility between packages? For example if I install serverless framework I get warning to upgrade package superagent. Now I want to know if I can upgrade the superagent package without breaking serverless. I checked package.json for dependencies of each of the following three serverless packages, but no superagent entry was found (could be dependency of dependency?).
$ npm install serverless serverless-http serverless-offline
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please upgrade to v9.0.0+ as we have fixed a public vulnerability with formidable dependency. Note that v9.0.0+ requires Node.js v14.18.0+. See https://github.com/ladjs/superagent/pull/1800 for insight. This project is supported and maintained by the team at Forward Email @ https://forwardemail.net

Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4

You can check npm ls --all

@Evert if I figured out from dependency tree that path-loader@1.0.12 requires superagent@7.1.6, then how to check if path-loader@1.0.12 is compatible with  superagent@9?

You could fork path-loader and try upgrading
